# centos history command delete flag throws how to use

Tags: linux, centos, command-history

When I try to delete a specific command from the history on
`centos Linux 3.10.0-693.21.1.e17.x86_64 #SMP`
on trying
`history -d 34`

I get an error saying

`Usage: history [-chrSLMT] [# number of events]`.

Comment: Your command is misspelled in the question. I'm on CentOS 3.10.0-1127.18.2.el7.x86_64 and I was able to delete a single history line using the command you described. "history -d #". Can you provide additional output if this isn't working? A screenshot or copy pasta of your terminal window?

Comment: that was just a typo writing it here in the OP.

Comment: Just making sure. Can you also edit the question with the additional information requested? A screenshot perhaps? Run history, run your command, and then post the output.

Answer (score 0):

When using the `history` command in the **tcsh** shell some of the arguments are not available compared to when using it in the **bash** shell.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).